# How do I set a link that will have the link look and fell but with no file (the content of the link will be in the same file with the link)

Tags: html

I'm writing an application, a reporter with heirarchy of folders and files, in the lower heirarchy level there are 2 types of reports: the simple one is a flat (non link) report that being presented as a single simple line.
the second type is a link with a general description in the header and if you press the link you get a full report.

example: if I run a telnet command, I will see the command in the header and if I want to see the entire session with the device I will press the link and it will be presented.

My problem is that most of this lined-files are small but the OS reserve a minimum space for every file so I loss alot of disk space for nothing.
The solution I want to implement is a "dummy" links, which will be presented and will behave like a regular links but actually will be stored in the same file like their "parent" (probably with alot of other links like them).

The solutions I saw so far are only for "jumping" inside a page but this is not what I'm looking for, I want it to be presented like a seperated file and I dont want the "parent" file to present this information at all (the only way to see it will be by pressing the link and even then it will present only this information and not the other file content).

any idea guys?

Comment: You mean having a link that takes a user to a specific part of the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I link to part of a page? (hash?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash)

Comment: The question appears to be a confusing formulation of a simple basic HTML question that has been asked multiple times (mostly with less than optimal answers, but still).

Comment: @Hovav You should update your question rather than posting comments.

Comment: @Hovav Can you find a image that shows us what you want to do. Your instructions aren't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

To link to a specific part in a web page, place an anchor link where you want the user to go to when they click a link with:

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

and link to it with:

```
Click <a href="#anchor">here</a>
```

You can replace "anchor" with a more descriptive name if needed.

---

To hide/show a div (the following code is untested, but should work)

**JQuery solution (If you're using JQuery):**

```
function toggle(divname) {
    $(divname).toggle();
}
```

The corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="content">some content</div>
<a onclick="toggle('content')">Click here to show/hide the content div!</a>
```

**Non-JQuery Solution:**

```
function toggle(divname) {
    var adiv = document.getElementById(divname);
    if (adiv.style.display === 'block' || adiv.style.display === '') {
        adiv.style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        adiv.style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div style="display:hidden" id="content">Content</div>
<a onclick="toggle('content')">Click here to show/hide the content div!</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got you right (or you didnt get me):
I tried this code:
`<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Frame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a name="link1">this is the inner link value<br>
        <b>check</b><br>
        </a>click <a href="#link1">here</a>
    </body>
</html>`

as you might see it does not work for me as I wanted it to: I want the "inner link data" to be hidden and presented only when I press the link...

Comment: @Hovav So you want the content to be hidden until someone clicks a link which then displays the hidden content?

Comment: @Hovav You can't do this with plain HTML.