# How to go to bottom of the page when submitbutton is clicked?

Tags: html, button, submit

On my website there is a contactform on the bottom of the page. When it is filled in and a user pressed the submitbutton, the page reloads but shows the top of the page. What do I need to adjust so when a user pushed the submitbutton, the page reloads and goes to the bottom of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: what about having some sort of "Thank you for contacting me" page, instead of reloading the same page?  I think it's less likely to confuse users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. [Set the hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash/2835151#2835151)
2. You can use jQuery and use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
3. Or native with [window.scrollBy(0,9999);](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html)
4. Submit the for through Ajax so you don't have to refresh the page.

Comment: Ow yes, forgot I could use javascript to scroll to the bottom, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put a named anchor to where you want to go after form sending:

```
<a name="afterform"><h1>Example: a heading</h1></a>
```

And then add that as a hash to the form action:

```
<form action="yourpage.html#afterform" ...
```