# FHIR search multiple values for the same parameter

Tags: hl7-fhir

For our patient registration system as a standalone web service, we want to use FHIR.

Applications that want to request data from the web service in some cases want to retrieve information about multiple patients. For example a list of last seen patients.

It would be really inefficient to search every patient based on id individually, because it will cause much overhead in networking and searching.
Is it possible to search for multiple patients with a set of IDs?

[Http should be able to handle this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request). I wonder if the FHIR standard supports this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's two choices. the first is

GET [base]/Patient?_id=1,2,3,4,5

Using commas like this is documented here: http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#combining

An alternative is to use a batch. This is a much more flexible arrangement - see http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#transaction