# Spring Data Rest - Sort by multiple properties

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an entity as below

```
Class Person{
String id;
String name;
String numberOfHands;
}
```

With Spring Data Rest (Gosling Release Train), I'm able to specify

```
localhost/Person?sort=name,asc
```

for sorting name name ascending. Now, in a case where I need to sort by numberOfHands descending and name ascending. I'm able to specify

```
localhost/Person?sort=numberOfHands,name,asc
```

But, I'm not able to specify

```
localhost/Person?sort=numberOfHands,desc,name,asc
```

Is there a way to specify multiple sort order?

Thanks!

Comment: Add multiple `sort` attributes. `sort=name,asc&sort=numberOfHands,desc`.

Comment: Great! that works.. But that is weird.. Except for a string being appended to URL, I'm not sure if there is a direct way of generating such URL through JavaScript.. Please let me know if I'm wrong..

Comment: Why would it be weird that is just the way the web (or URLs) work. You can generate whatever URL you like with javascript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request.

Comment: @M.Deinum - You might wanna turn this into an answer as it's correct. If you have trouble creating such URIs via JavaScript, blame JavaScript or the library you're using. :)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### Solution (tl;dr)

When wanting to sort on multiple fields you simply put the `sort` parameter multiple times in the URI. For example `your/uri?sort=name,asc&sort=numberOfHands,desc`. Spring Data is then capable of constructing a `Pageable` object with multiple sorts.

### Explanation

There is not really a defined standard on how to submit multiple values for a parameter in a URI. See [Correct way to pass multiple values for same parameter name in GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request).

However there is some information in the [Java Servlet Spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) which hints on how Java servlet containers parse request parameters.

> The `getParameterValues` method returns an array of `String` objects containing all the parameter values associated with a parameter name. ... - *Java Servlet Spec, section 3.1*

The sample further in that section states (although it mixes request and body data)

> For example, if a request is made with a query string of `a=hello` and a post body of `a=goodbye&a=world`, the resulting parameter set would be ordered `a=hello, goodbye, world`.

This sample shows that when a parameter (`a` in the example) is presented multiple times the results will be aggregated into a `String[]`.

Comment: https://bezkoder.com/spring-data-sort-multiple-columns

Answer (score 66):

Here is how to construct the multi Sort object manually/programatically.

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(
    Sort.Order.asc("name"),
    Sort.Order.desc("numberOfHands"));
return personRepository.findAll(sort);
```

Note: This solution does not directly solve the original question asked, but may help visitors that landed on this question while searching for a solution how to sort on multiple properties from a backend perspective / in a somewhat "hardcoded" way. (this solution does not require/take any URI parameters)

Comment: Interesting, though I guess this will only work on the server side.

Comment: Yes, this works when you need to "hardcode" it server side. It uses the [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) class from Spring data. I have clarified the answer so it's hopefully more clear now :-)

Comment: Say I use JPQL and join across multiple tables. And I want to sort it based on two columns. One from the first table and another from second table. if I pass it as `Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC,"first_table_col","second_table_col")` , I get an exception saying "second_table_col" not found in First_table. Is it possible ?

Comment: @iamL perhaps try with the prefix of the second table?

Comment: @PimHazebroek .. That is what I ended up doing. Cleared alias names for the tables and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Second way to construct multi sort in repository:

`return this.bookRepository.findAll(Sort.by("published").descending().and(Sort.by("title")).a cending());`

Answer (score 1):

When dynamic fields are there then you simply do match with fields and add in sorting list like.

```
List<Sort.Order> sorts= new ArrayList<>();
if (sort == "name" && sortingOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("DESC")) {
   sorts.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"name"));
} else if (sort == "numberOfHands" && sortingOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("DESC")) {
  sorts.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"numberOfHands"));
}
     
return personRepository.findAll(Sort.by(sorts));
```

If you are using Pagination then directly add in PageRequest Request.

```
return personRepository.findPersons(PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by(sorts)));
```