# Jpa Criteria API count

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I've been trying to get total rows count and to do so, I've used JPA Criteria API but it throws an error at `Long count = em.createQuery(sc).getSingleResult();` line and saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified` . I've done some research but couldn't narrow the problem.

Here's my code snippet;

```
@PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;

......

public Page<UserDTO> findByCriteria(String filters, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDTO.class);
        Root<UserDTO> iRoot = cq.from(UserDTO.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filters)) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(iRoot.<String>get("login")), "%" + filters.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        Predicate[] predArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
        predicates.toArray(predArray);

        CriteriaQuery<Long> sc = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        sc.select(cb.count(iRoot));

        sc.where(predArray);
        Long count = em.createQuery(sc).getSingleResult();

        cq.where(predArray);

        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>(2);
        orders.add(cb.asc(iRoot.get("name")));
        orders.add(cb.asc(iRoot.get("desc")));

        cq.orderBy(orders);
        TypedQuery<UserDTO> query = em.createQuery(cq);

        Page<UserDTO> result = new PageImpl<UserDTO>(query.getResultList(), pageable, count);


        return result;
    }
```

**EDITED AND WORKING CODE;**

```
public Page<UserDTO> findByCriteria(String columnName, String filters, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDTO.class);
        Root<UserDTO> iRoot = cq.from(UserDTO.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filters)) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(iRoot.<String>get(columnName)), "%" + filters.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        Predicate[] predArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
        predicates.toArray(predArray);

        Long count = calculateCount(filters);

        cq.where(predArray);

        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>(2);
        orders.add(cb.asc(iRoot.get("firstName")));
        orders.add(cb.asc(iRoot.get("lastName")));

        cq.orderBy(orders);
        TypedQuery<UserDTO> query = em.createQuery(cq);

        Page<UserDTO> result = new PageImpl<UserDTO>(query.getResultList(), pageable, count);


        return result;
    }

    public Long calculateCount(String filters) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> sc = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<UserDTO> iRoot = sc.from(UserDTO.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filters)) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(iRoot.<String>get("login")), "%" + filters.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        Predicate[] predArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
        predicates.toArray(predArray);

        sc.select(cb.count(iRoot));

        sc.where(predArray);
        Long count = em.createQuery(sc).getSingleResult();

        return count;

    }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat he actually used that code already

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sorry I thought he was missing `cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(MyEntity.class)));`

Comment: I've tried that solution but it doesn't work though. That's why I post this question. Maybe there is something wrong that I did. @XtremeBaumer

Comment: Have you tried creating a method that only does the `count`?

Comment: I think it would be kinda better to out-source each query and create the result from that

Comment: Sadly I can't share some code here now because of the duplicate mark. As soon as it is lifted, I will post some code, but I can't promise that it will work

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly add [CriteriaQuery#from()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/AbstractQuery.html#from(java.lang.Class)) method? `sc.from(iRoot);`

Comment: Seperated method solved my problem! But why? I mean, I moved same codes to just different method. How did it matter? @ScaryWombat

Comment: @BurakN. add your updated code and we might be able to tell you whats the difference

Comment: Updated! @XtremeBaumer

Comment: I would guess that if you add this line `sc.from(UserDTO.class);` in your old code, then it will work too. That line is missing in your old code and specifies from which `Root`-class the query should select

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, I couldn't sort the data by using `pageable.getSort()` because I don't know where to put that. Could you please help me to do the sorting too? @XtremeBaumer

Comment: i am not common with `pageable.getSort()`, but the results should be order by your `orders` which both state `ASC`

Comment: Yes but I want to make it dynamic. That's why I need to use `pageable.getSort()` @XtremeBaumer

Comment: I assume you can get a string like shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692097/jpa-criteriaquery-implements-spring-data-pageable-getsort). Then you can determine with an IF, whether the string contains ASC or DESC and use the right case of `orders.add(cb.asc(iRoot.get("lastName")));`. If you tell me which information you can get from `pageable.getSort()`, I might be able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As anticipated in the comment, you need to explicitly add [CriteriaQuery#from()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/AbstractQuery.html#from(java.lang.Class)) method:

```
sc.from(UserDTO.class);
```

The `from` method is often not used because the API provider defaults to the entity class specified in the `CriteriaQuery` constructor. Not in this case however, because the class is a `Long` and it doesn't correspond to an entity class.

## See also:

[Oracle's JAVA EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html)