# Add orderBy sorting into search Specification

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, specifications

I want to extend this Specification by adding order by params.

***Search options DTO:***

```
public class ProductSearchParams {
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private LocalDateTime publishedAt;
    private String sort;
    private List<String> sortBy;
}

public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProducts(ProductSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Product> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getTitle() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"), params.getTitle()));
            }
            if (params.getType() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), params.getType()));
            }
            if (params.getPublishedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("publishedAt"), params.getPublishedAt()));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
        return productService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(productMapper::toFullDTO);
    }
```

I tried this:

```
public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProducts(ProductSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Product> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getTitle() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"), params.getTitle()));
            }
            if (params.getType() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), params.getType()));
            }
            if (params.getPublishedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("publishedAt"), params.getPublishedAt()));
            }
            if (params.getPublishedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("publishedAt"), params.getPublishedAt()));
            }
            query.orderBy(builder.desc((root.join(Prodotto_.listaQuoteIng))
                    .get(QuotaIngrediente_.perc_ing)));

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
        return productService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(productMapper::toFullDTO);
    }
```

I can't find a solution how to implement this. Can you give me advice where I'm wrong?

Comment: why do you need that? You already have pageable which contains sort. So maybe you are missing something?

Comment: I just want to add this option into above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate `pageable` object before call `findAll` method:

```
// sort = "desc" sortBy = ["listaQuoteIng.perc_ing"]
List<Sort.Order> orders = params.getSortBy().stream().map(s -> new Sort.Order("asc".equals(params.getSort()) ? ASC : DESC, s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), new Sort(orders));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to use the `sortBy` list to specify the sort order? The following should work:

```
query.orderBy(sortyBy.stream()
    .map(root::get)
    .map(cb::desc)
    .toList());
```

You can also pass the sort order to `Pageable` via the `sort` query param (e.g. `sort=name,asc&sort=type,desc&sort=listaQuoteIng.perc_ing,desc`) and easily adapt it to Criteria API, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906871/1092818).

Comment: yes, but can you show me how to add you code into the code that I want to extend?

Comment: Not sure I follow, replacing the `query.orderBy(...)` line with the above code should do the trick