# URL query param for multiple sort

Tags: java, rest, api, sorting

I am designing a REST API which would need to bee sorted on multiple parameter.

I am trying to use something like http://books?sort=+author,-datepublished

But I don't know how to write a custom QueryParam to parse the sort.

Comment: This is a Springboot project?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Yes working on Spring

Comment: Take at look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034533/1715121

Comment: Yeah I had a look at it. the problem is I don't wanna specify sort a number of time in my url. I wanna use single sort with multiple values where - denotes ASC and + denote  DESC