# Spring Data custom Order like "order by FIELD(...)" in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

i am trying to set the same order in Spring Data for Practice object as illustrated below in mysql:

```
select * from practice order by FIELD(id, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3) desc
```

For now, i can set just something like

```
new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id")
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with column-indices, but [this might perhaps be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254206/1682559) for sorting on multiple columns in SpringData.

Comment: Using ORM frameworks is great until you have to do something which is "non standard".. Maybe you can do `new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "FIELD(id, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3)")`. But most likely you would have to use a raw query here if that framework supports that feature..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, unfortunately your solution throwing org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property FIELD(id, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3) found for type

Comment: @RaymondNijland are you using spring data jpa as dependency?

Comment: *"are you using spring data jpa as dependency?"* @Hatice i believe i did in the past as i did Java programming more then a decade ago..  i believe when you need to made a custom sort you would need to made a Repository and use `@Query("<query>", nativeQuery = true)` in that Repository   more or less explained on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query  ..  Also notice a RDMS function `LENGHT(firstname)` is used with `JpaSort.unsafe(..)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland So sorry Raymond, I tagged you wrongly. I want to ask question Aleksei. Because, I will suggest the same documentation him, but I could not understand what he has dependencies.

Comment: No worries .. @Hatice atleast i've given some more research options in the manual which seams into getting a solution for the topicstarter

Comment: *" I want to ask question Aleksei. Because, I will suggest the same documentation him, but I could not understand what he has dependencies. "* ... also the topicstarter could have shared more code indeed @Hatice

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, i'am using spring data jpa.As for native query, i can't use it. I have to generate org.springframework.data.domain.Sort object and send it to service layer. So, maybe exists a variant, where i can create only org.springframework.data.domain.Sort object using native sql query?

Comment: *"So, maybe exists a variant, where i can create only org.springframework.data.domain.Sort object using native sql query? "* check [5.3.5. Using Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) in the manual?  The Document was the same as i provided before assuming `new Sort(..)` in that context is `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` object, which is not clear in that document..  Maybe in that context you can use `JpaSort.unsafe("FIELD(id, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3) [desc]")` aswell..