# Regular expression in Java to match a String containing + character

Tags: java, regex, rest, query-string

I'm using annotation [`javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) to validate the sort parameter. The value of this parameter must be: `+id` or `+originId` for ascending, and `-id` or `-originId` for descending.

The syntax of this parameter can not be modified.

```
@Valid @Pattern(regexp= SORT_REGEXP, message = SORT + NOT_VALID)
@RequestParam(name = SORT, required = false) String sort,
```

This is what I have as my regular expression:

```
^[+-]id$|^[+-]originId$
```

I have also tried escaping the plus sign `+` like:

```
^[\\+-]id$|^[\\+-]originId$
```

If I use the `-id` or the `-originId`, it's been validated but when I use the `+` it says that it's not matching the pattern.

How to match the plus-sign with a regular expression?

Comment: the regular expression seems to be working: https://ideone.com/oMPWM8 - we need more information

Comment: Related question using `asc` and `desc` instead of mathematical signs: [Spring Data Rest - Sort by multiple properties - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018127/spring-data-rest-sort-by-multiple-properties/33034533#33034533)

Comment: Within URLs the `+` is usually decoded to space: [url - Why is Spring de-coding + (the plus character) on application/json get requests? and what should I do about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270372). See also "Requires URL percent encoding" for Lucene-syntax in [Paging, sorting, filtering and retrieving specific fields in your RESTful API | by Guillaume Viguier-Just | Medium](https://medium.com/@guillaume.viguierjust/paging-sorting-filtering-and-retrieving-specific-fields-in-your-restful-api-a0d289bc574a)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern can be simplified by specifying the boundaries outside your match and using a group.

```
^[+-](id|originId)$
```

Comment: Thanks for your improvement suggestion! Any idea of how to solve the issue with the + character?

Comment: This should solve the issue with the `+` character. Tested with `Pattern.compile("^[+-](id|originId)$").matcher("+id")`

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I try to send the request with +id and using that regex is still saying that doesn't match. I know it should work but is failing...

Comment: The regex is good, the problem is elsewhere. How do you send a request? Remember, that for example in an url a simple plus character is interpreted as a space and should be escaped as %2B

Comment: Thanks Alex! That was the problem. I try with %2B instead of + and works.