# Is there a way to put multiple parameters in routing parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a route `get '/catalog/:gender/' => 'catalog#gender'`. The `:gender` param is used in my controller like so `@products = Product.where(gender: params[:gender]).all`.

So I can use `/catalog/male/` to get all male products and `/catalog/female/` to get all female products. The question is, is there a way somebody could possibly pass both `male` and `female` parameters and get all the products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `/catalog/all/` to get all products, and in your controller:

```
if params[:gender] == "all"
  @products = Product.all
else
  @products = Product.where(gender: params[:gender])
end
```

Or render `gender` params optional `get '/catalog(/:gender)'` and then in your controller:

```
if params[:gender]
  @products = Product.where(gender: params[:gender])
else
  @products = Product.all
end
```

---

To complete answer, [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) can resolve your issue too.

Let's create a route `/catalog/`, and submit an array like `/catalog?gender[]=male&gender[]=female`.

```
# params[:gender] = ["male", "female"]
# SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."gender" IN ('male', 'female')
@products = Catalog.where(gender: params[:gender])
```

Answers to complete this solution:

- [Correct way to pass multiple values for same parameter name in GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728298/4434754)
- [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/4434754)

Comment: Thank you. But I was wondering if somebody could possibly pass few parameters to the link and get few categories of the product. I guess the answer is "No".