# Can I pass multiple parameters to get multiple result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating an API where I have a table named *invoices* where *customerType* is a column. *customerType* can be of only four possible values **IE.** PCT, RVN, INT or OTH.

Now, I want to pass URLs like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/quatertodate?group-by=customerNumber&customertype=RVN,INT
http://localhost:3000/api/quatertodate?group-by=customerNumber&customertype=RVN,INT,OTH
http://localhost:3000/api/quatertodate?group-by=customerNumber
http://localhost:3000/api/quatertodate?group-by=customerNumber&customertype=PCT
http://localhost:3000/api/quatertodate?group-by=customerNumber&customertype=INT,PCT
```

But, the issue is whenever I pass a single *customertype* or no *customertype* at all, it works but whenever I pass multiple parameters in *customertype* it returns **null** when it should be returning combined result of those by performing internal *OR* query.

In *index* method of *controller* I have:

```
def index
    @invoices=if params[:'group-by'].present?
        if params[:'group-by'].to_s == "customerNumber" 

            if params[:customertype].present?
                Invoice.where(customerType: params[:customertype])
            else
                Invoice.order('customerNumber')
            end
        end
    end 
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED QUATERLY INVOICES', data: @invoices}, status: :ok
end
```

**NOTE:** The closest answer I could find is [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771904/is-there-a-way-to-put-multiple-parameters-in-routing-parameters). Any help or explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to query `Invoice` where `customerType` equals `RVN,INT`

You might need to perform `split` on the `customertype` param:

```
def index
    @invoices=if params[:'group-by'].present?
        if params[:'group-by'].to_s == "customerNumber" 

            if params[:customertype].present?
                Invoice.where(customerType: params[:customertype].split(","))
            else
                Invoice.order('customerNumber')
            end
        end
    end 
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED QUATERLY INVOICES', data: @invoices}, status: :ok
end
```

This will generate for you a query:

```
SELECT `invoices`.* FROM `invoices` WHERE `invoices`.`customerType` IN ('RVN', 'INT')
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT `invoices`.* FROM `invoices` WHERE `invoices`.`customerType` = 'RVN,INT'
```

Comment: Your solution works. But your explanation clears the doubt. :D