# Generate a list in a URL with Flask's url_for

Tags: python, flask, query-string, marshmallow, webargs

I am using webargs to parse parameters from `request.args` with Marshmallow and pass them as arguments to a Flask view. My client uses a comma separated list to represent multiple values for a key:

```
/queues/generate?queue_id=4&include_ids=1,2,3
```

To parse this I use Marshmallow's `DelimitedList` field.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from webargs import use_args
from webargs.fields import DelimitedList

class GenerationParamsSchema(Schema):
    queue_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    include_ids = DelimitedList(fields.Integer(), required=False)

@queues.route('/generate_content', methods=['GET'])
@use_args(GenerationParamsSchema(strict=True))
def generate_content_count(generation_params):
    ...
```

However, if I generate the URL with Flask's `url_for`, it produces duplicate keys for each value:

```
url_for('queues.generate', queue_id=4, include_ids=[1, 2, 3])
```

```
/queues/generate?queue_id=4&include_ids=1&include_ids=2&include_ids=3
```

Parsing this with a `DelimitedList` field only captures the first value. Changing to a `List` field correctly captures the values again. So either my Flask URLs fail, or my client URLs fail.

I can't change how my client generates URLs, so I'd like to stick with parsing using the `DelimitedField`. How can I make `url_for` generate the same style?

Answer (score 2):

[There's no standard for specifying multiple values for a key in a query string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request) Flask, browsers, and many other web technologies use the "repeat key" style that you see with `url_for` and `request.args`. Your client has chosen to use a different style.

If you want `url_for` to generate the delimited style, you'll need to pre-process the values you pass to `url_for`. Write a wrapper around `url_for` and use it instead.

```
from flask import url_for as _url_for

@app.template_global()
def url_for(endpoint, **values):
    for key, value in values.items():
        if isinstance(value, (tuple, list)):
            values[key] = ','.join(value)

    return _url_for(endpoint, **values)
```

Keep in mind that `requests.args` only understands the repeat key style, so you'll have to parse, with webargs or otherwise, any incoming comma separated values. It may be easier to generate the repeat key style from your client instead.