# Encode multiple query parameters with vue-resource without `[]`s

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm querying a REST API using [vue-resource's](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#methods) `$http.get` via:

```
this.$http.get('/api', {
    params: {
        id: [1,2,3],
    },
});
```

and this produces the query

```
/api?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

But my endpoint expects

```
/api?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

Is there a way to tell `vue-resource` to encode multiple parameters like this?

I'd like to avoid constructing my own query string, but that's the alternative I can come up with.

Comment: There is a confusion for me. if your endpoint route is '/api' then the params will automatically be passed.If your endpoint is '/api/:id1/:id2/:id3' you should make request like this `this.$http.get(\`/api/${id1}/${id2}/${id3}\`)`. Also having the same variable in query will result in errors.

Comment: I didn't say `/api/:id1/:id2/:id3`, I said `/api?id=1&id=2&id=3`. Quoting Wikipedia, "[While there is no definitive standard, most web frameworks allow multiple values to be associated with a single field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms)". I wonder if `vue-resource` can cater to different standards of passing multiple values to the same parameter. `id[]` resembles the way PHP does it. [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org/) does it differently. Welcome to the Wild West. :-)

Comment: You said /api?id=1&id=2&id=3 which will converted to a dynamic route /api/:id1/:id2/:id3. Maybe I am missing something, but I am trying to help you

Comment: I'm not sure where this conversion to a dynamic route comes in. Maybe you're thinking of the behavior of another back-end web-framework than the one I'm working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking by internal implementation of query params [serialize](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/src/url/index.js#L115) function of `vue-resource`, I can say - no, there is no way to customize query params serialize function in `vue-resource`.

There is [no standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request) to pass a collection of values via query string, so format is more framework specific. And while both `vue-resource` and `axios` by default use brackets format to serialize arrays, the second one allows to configure custom query serialize function via `paramsSerializer` option.

Guess, the main reason that there is no standard, is because it is quite easy to create custom function on front-end to serialize query params.

You can use [qs.js](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library to solve your issue

```
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] }, { indices: false });
```

Or here is an example of custom function from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object), but modified to your request:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jto4b5ra/)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I'll consider Axios (which I encountered earlier today), qs.js and simply building my own query string formatter.