# String custom sorting order in url

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-data

Is there any option to pass custom sorting order in url? For example, I have some statuses (OPEN, CLOSED, PENDING) and I want to order it like PENDING, CLOSED, OPEN. Can I pass this order in url (I don't want to use ascending, descending)? Something like:

```
/tasks?sort=status,[PENDING,CLOSED,OPEN]
```

Comment: `/tasks?sort=PENDING&sort=CLOSED&sort=OPEN`

Comment: This can be received in spring as a `List<String>` giving you the sort order

Comment: Some related literature [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What this endpoint. A Spring MVC Controller? A Spring Data Rest controller? What is the datastore?

Answer (score 1):

There is no custom ordering feature as you need. You have to design with your own efforts.

You need to implement a business which includes these steps:

- Pass your argument which includes the order of the field to a server by querystring or JSON (more preferable IMO).
- After that, you can take that array which includes the order of your objects.
- As a last, order/recreate your list based on a field which listed inside that array.