# Multiple query parameters with same name

Tags: javascript, express, url, url-parameters

I want to know how does EXPRESS parse multiple query parameters with the same name; I couldn't find any useful reference anywhere. I want to know specifically about EXPRESS, how is it going to treat this URL `www.example.com/page?id=1&id=2&id=3.....id=n`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to pass multiple values for same parameter name in GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request)

Comment: No, it talks about which method is better, not how they work. Also, I think each framework has its own ways to parse things, especially for such corner-cases and that's why I mentioned EXPRESS. I saw that before asking. Thanks anyway!

Comment: QueryParser in Express is configurable, the default configuration ("extended") uses [qs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/qs) to parse query strings, the simple mode uses  Node’s native query parser [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html), and you can also define your own parser. I couldn't find anything from the linked documentations concerning double names, but you can test it.

Comment: Hey @Teemu, thanks for replying, as you mentioned, I've found some correlations. From what I've understood, It's storing them in an array which in my opinion is a good way for bypassing filters for local file inclusion. I just want some concrete documentation or RFC section supporting some similar argument.

Comment: As Eduardo has stated in the [suggested dup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728298/1169519), "_there is no defined standard_", you've to examine the documentation of the implementations, which in these two cases don't seem to contain the wanted information. Hence the only way to find out is testing ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the usual [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query). Whenever there's multiple query parameters with the same name, `req.query[paramName]` will return an array instead of the value. So in your case:

```
app.get("/page", (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.query
    console.log("ID is "+ id) 
});

// GET www.example.com/page?id=1&id=2&id=3
// ID is ["1", "2", "3"]

// GET www.example.com/page?id=12345
// ID is 12345
```