# Django (GET) - Is it posible to pass multiple values in only one parameter, instead of multiple parameters called the same

Tags: django, forms, url, parameters, get

I'm developing an web app with Django to query and download data from multiple weather stations. It's almost everything good but something that I don't like it's that when I filter by stations, the form passes them to the URL like this:

```
https://my-server/stations?station_name=1&station_name=2&station_name=3
```

And since the number of selected stations can reach more than 250 (this added to the fact that spatial data are also passed in the URL as coordinates, polygons...), I would like to know if there is any way to obtain the "station_name" parameter in a list format like this or similar, for me to later divide it in my views.py:

```
https://my-server/stations?station_name=1%3B2%3B3
```

On the other hand, I'm not sure if there are any contraindications when generating too long URLs, if not I have no problem maintaining the current format, but otherwise I would like to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** If it helps, I'm using the Select2MultipleWidget widget for this field.

Comment: You should include the `Select2MultipleWidget` reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request

Comment: @ArakkalAbu What do you mean?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane Very usefull to answer the last question. So there is no standard about doing that one way or another, it's good to know that, thanks.