# Validating an array in query params

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to validate a query parameter `type` that can have one or multiple values (like `?type=type1,type2`), and I did something like this :

```php
if ($request->has('type')) {
    $request->query->set('type', explode(',', $request->query('type')));
}

$params = $request->validate([
    'type' => [
        'array',
        Rule::in(['type1', 'type2'])
    ]
]);
```

Is there a cleaner way in laravel (8) to handle this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request 
This might help!

Comment: `'type' => 'required|in:'.implode(',', $request->query('type'),`