# PHP Get Parameter List

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I am trying to extract a list of parameters from a GET URL passed to my .php code..
Have found a few articles on  here and elsewhere but none seem to answer this specific question.

.. my URL string :
`http://localhost/includes/runner_AddToEvent.php?eventSelector=155&eventSelector=154&eventSelector=151`

If I use :
`var_dump($_GET);`

This results in :

```
array (size=1)
  'eventSelector' => string '151' (length=3)
```

I want the array returned in full so not too sure why var_dump() returns only the last element... ?
Help gratefully received, thanks in advance.

Have tried using POST method but that makes no difference..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request

Comment: Thank you for your super fast response! Clearly I missed that post which wasnt prompted before I posted this ... thank you.

Comment: If you can't change how the parameters are named, you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the raw query string from the URL. You'll have to parse it yourself.