# How to add multiple query parameters in Angular with same name?

Tags: angular, router

Is there any way to add multiple query parameters with same name in Angular using the HTML expression only?

I am building Filters in my app and needs to match the URL structure with API.

```
/users?tag=One&tag=Two
```

```
<a
      class="dropdown-item mx-2"
      role="button"
      *ngFor="let tag of tags"
      routerLink="./"
      [queryParams]="{ tag: tag }"
      [queryParamsHandling]="'merge'"
    >
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [name]="tag" />
      {{ tag }}
    </a>
```

It works fine when merging with different names, but seems to be working as `set(name, value)` behind the scene instead the `append(name, value)` mode to accept multiple values with same key name.

Here is my example in stackblitz = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwattp

Comment: I want to keep it angular expression only or a pipe to keep the code short, because there are 10+ filters (tags, source, user_id, created etc) and many components to apply the filter...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a well defined spec for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728298/2398593 and therefore I wouldn't be surprised if angular implemented this as a map. You could create a little helper so that if the same key comes up multiple times, you chain the values in the url with a coma, so that `id=1&id=2` would become `id=1,2`

Comment: @maxime1992 can i do this with a re-usable pipe? any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom click and redirect after calculate parameters:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  tags = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  sources = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'twitter.com'];

  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly router: Router
  ) {}

  navigateWithTag(selectedTag: string) {
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((p) => {
      const tagParams = p.tag ? [...p.tag, selectedTag] : [selectedTag];

      const queryParams: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: { ...p, tag: tagParams },
      };

      this.router.navigate(['.'], queryParams);
    });
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<a
  class="dropdown-item mx-2"
  role="button"
  *ngFor="let tag of tags"
  (click)="navigateWithTag(tag)"
>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [name]="tag" />
  {{ tag }}
</a>
```

Comment: I want to keep it angular expression only to keep the code short, because there are 10+ filters (tags, source, user_id, created etc). Any options to manage it in expressions only? like `[queryParams]="{  tag: tag, ...existingTag }"`

Comment: I think you should use a custom directive. Example: 
```
<a
  class="dropdown-item mx-2"
  role="button"
  *ngFor="let tag of tags"
  [paramManageKey]="tag"
>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [name]="tag" />
  {{ tag }}
</a>
```
Then in directive, handle click event for navigate and manage params via a field