# CSS Not Loading when Section Referenced from different Page

Tags: html, css, anchor

Ok, I was able to link a specific section of a page from another page, but for some reason none of the CSS is loading with the page being referenced.  What can be causing this?

In hopes of providing context, this is the code I'm using to reference (which works only to link the section correctly, but no styling in the entire page is shown)

(Page link)

```
<a href="dog.html/#dog-food-a">Dog Food</a>
```

(Section being referenced in different page)

```
<a name="dog-food-a" id="dog-food-a">Food</a>
```

I was able to acquire the referencing information from the following link, but I'm having trouble finding somebody else with the same 'lack of css' issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835151/2488264

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: I didn't understand your question.Can you elaborate plz??

Answer (score 0):

The `id` tag specifies the ID of an element, not to what element your doing an anchor tag.

Having that in mind, it is always http://mypage.com/this.html#my-anchor

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to remote accesss that link and section?
if your answer is **YES** i should say you have to **load entire target page** Or load `<link>` tag of target page  Or use same *CSS* file for both pages
if I dont get the right point forgive me