# How to use a specific div as the landings index?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple one-page website for a school assignment and it has 3 different divs above each other.

My question is how to have the website center the 2nd div of the three when you enter the website, so that you can either scroll up (to see div 1) or down (to see div 3). So, when you load the page the first thing you see is div 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: @Paulie_D This is a little bit different. Bambi isn't linking anyone to the site, like in your article.

Comment: have a look here as suggested by Paulie_D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: please provide a sample of the page you've created so we can give you a sample of the solution

Comment: @Toast Same principle applies....it's called hashing. If the URL has the hash, the page will go there first.

Answer (score -1):

Here:


Make your landing page auto-redirect to your home page. Replace `#yourdivhere` with the `id` of your div. 

*Landing Page*

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://your.site/#yourdivhere" />
</head>
```

*Your Page*

```
<div id="firstdiv">Your content</div>
<div id="yourdivhere">Your div you want to center</div>
<div id="lastdiv">Your content</div>
```

Comment: If it's a one page site...why do you now have two pages?

Comment: @Paulie_D I found a better way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

**I found a better way.**
This is a very simple script insertion that you can insert in your site.

```
<body>
<script>
if(window.location.href != "http://your.site/#yourcenterdiv"){
  window.location.href = "http://your.site/#yourcenterdiv";
}
</script>
<div id="yourfirstdiv">CONTENT</div>
<div id="yourcenterdiv">CONTENT HERE</div>
<div id="yourlastdiv">MORE CONTENT</div>
</body>
```

Please note this only works with http:// urls. It is pretty simple to modify the script to add other urls however, just add something like `|| "other://example.url/#yourcenterdiv"` to the if statement.