# How to call a particular div using html hyperlink from another page?

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="something.html#div2">some</a>
```

something.html

```
<div id="div1">IMAGES</div>
<div id="div2"> content</div>
```

The problem is i have few images in div 1 tag..when i click href it doesnt go to div2

Comment: You don't have more than one element with the ID div2 do you?

Comment: The code you posted looks to me like it should work. For further help, consider posting a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: code is working properly if div1 contains text alone...my problem is my div1 has few images...so when i click my href it doesnt goes to div2

Answer (score 1):

You'll want an anchor tag for that, as so:

```
<a name="div2"></a>
```

Put that tag in the div you want to shortcut to.

Comment: An anchor tag is actually not necessary - you can use an id as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a): This attribute (`name`) is required in an anchor defining a target location within a page. A value for name is similar to a value for the id core attribute and should be an alphanumeric identifier unique to the document. Under the HTML 4.01 specification, id and name both can be used with the <a> element as long as they have identical values.
Usage note: This attribute is obsolete in HTML5, use global attribute id instead.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, You're right!  Thanks for noting that.

Comment: code is working properly if div1 contains text alone...my problem is my div1 has few images...so when i click my href it doesnt goes to div2

Comment: @DineshChakravarthy I don't see any img tags in your example. Please provide an example that actually reflects your question/problem

Comment: favorite
 

<a href="something.html#div2">some</a>

something.html

<div id="div1"><img src="tour5.jpg" ></img><img src="tour5.jpg" ><img src="tour5.jpg" ><img src="tour5.jpg" ></div>
<div id="div2"> content</div>