# Link to halfway down another page in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, hyperlink

I am trying to create a link from my homepage to another page a certain place which is not the top of the page, in sharepoint 2013. There's a method I found somewhere on the internet which allows me to link halfway down but only on the same page.

Does anyone know how to link from one page to another and how to determine where it loads.

Comment: Does a standard hash work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: It does look like you just want to jump to a specific ID on a page. So just use an anchor with `href="#IDofObject"` or `href="page.html#IDofObject"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use anchors to arrive at that certain place on another page. Your anchor must refer to either the element's name or id properties.

Here is an anchor link example:

```
<a href="anotherpage.aspx#element">Go to a certain place on another page</a>
```

Here are examples of elements with names and ids:

```
<h1 name="element">Target Element</h1>
```

or

```
<h1 id="element">Target Element</h1>
```