# Scroll down on page after expansion of collapsible div

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a collapsible div for our Refund policy at the bottom of my page (on the same line as our copyright).  The div collapses and expands correctly.  However, I need the page to scroll down so the user can see the text. I have looked on the web and would prefer to stay away from a javascript option if I can.  I found HTML that I modified and though it would work.  Unfortunately it doesn't.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refund" onclick="location.href='#refund';">Refund Policy</button>

<div id="refund" class="collapse">
```

The code looks correct but it doesn't scroll.  What am I missing or will I need to go with a Javascript option?

I am doing this in C# MVC if that can have an effect but I don't think it will.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: @unpollo it is not a duplicate. Because I found that link as well as others. That one is only using an a ref.  I am using a button that does two things at once - expands the div and then also scrolls. So it is unique.