# Linux directory folder that begins with a symbols

Tags: linux, url, web-hosting

I am working on a website and noticed that as I was making up folder names that any folder name that begins with a # is not recognized from the web browser.  For example: example.com/#example/index.html will not work.  Whereas example.com/%23example/index.html works. In the same example using !@$%*& will work file without encoding.  Curious why and how to make it work if I wanted it to. I read this article: [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid).  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `%23` instead of `#` in the URL?

Comment: @choroba yes i fixed it i meant to type % instead of & but %23 works but not the pound sign.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid characters might have a special meaning for the browser. For example # is used to create links on the same page. Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash).

Comment: the link i referenced said that # is not a invalid character.  As a directory folder I have not seen where its invalid either.

Comment: # is valid, but it has a special meaning. It indicates that link leads to an anchor(id="anchor") on the page. So if you use example.com/#example/index.html the browser is trying to find the id="example..." on the page example.com/index.html.

Comment: so why would example.com/%23example/index.html work?  Its the same thing in my head.  I know its encoding but its just converting the # so its the same folder.

Comment: The explicit character # has a special meaning for the browser, while using %23 allows you to use this character if needed without the special meaning. I a lot of programming languages you have characters with a special meaning, for example \, you might not be able to use it directly, because it introduces a control sequence. But you can use \\ to generate a single back slash in a string. It is pretty much the same concept.