# How I link to part of a page on google sites?

Tags: html, google-sites

I am making a website and I am required to use Google Sites. I am trying to make a table of contents, much like Wikipedia has, where links go to a specific part of the page rather then another web page. I've already tried using the method provided in "[How do I link to part of a page? (hash?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash)" by putting the following code in a HTML box:

```
<p><a href="#jump">This is a link</a></p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="jump">hi</p>
```

When the link is clicked it tries to go to another page.

I have been testing this in Firefox and Chrome, although if a solution only works in one browser it would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this does not work inside a HTML box.

You have to use Google's HTML editing of the main code.

The `id` attribute does not work here so instead you have to use an anchor tag and a name attribute, which can be used just like the id was used before.

Here is some sample code:

```
<p><a href="#jump">This is a link</a></p>
<!-- stuff here -->
<p><a name="jump">hi</a></p>
```