# Hyperlink to section of a page

Tags: html

This is going to read like an extremely silly and novice question.... But I cannot seem to work out what is wrong with my code.

I want to have my menu links at the top the page link to different sections within the same page. I have read up on a few various topics including [How do I link to part of a page? (hash?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash) but I just can't get it working....  Any help would be great.

If it helps I am building this on codepen.....not sure if that makes any difference.

```
The code I am using is:
<a href="#services">Services</a>

<div id="services><h3>Our Services</h3></div>
```

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id, with lots of activity.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double quote is missing at the end of services.

```
<div id="services"><h3>Our Services</h3></div>
```

Syntax highlighting is your friend !

Comment: Urghh.....I feel like such a moron atm.... Thank you. I am now going to pump my bloodstream with needed caffeine....

Comment: Well, if my answer helped you, could you please accept it so your question is closed? Thanks