# Href with bookmark to another page not working

Tags: html, href

I am trying to make a hyperlink to a specific part of another page, but it wont do anything. Here is how I have it set:

```
<a href="eng#about">ENG</a>
```

and on the "eng" page I have

```
<section class="about" id="about">
```

But when clicking on link, nothing happens.... If i use middle mouse to open link in new tab (or right click-open in new tab or new window) it will do exactly what I want it to do in my currently open tab, not in new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link to part of a page? (hash?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash)

Answer (score 1):

Try `<a href="eng.html#about">ENG</a>`

Comment: Then you could use <a name="about" class="about">Content to Link To</a>