# How to scrollTop an anchor in home page by another page (eg.: about)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Has anyone had this problem before? I am on an internal page (like about.html) and I want to scrollTop to an anchor in home page (like home.html#sectionID), but I don't know how can I do that with jQuery.. I've already tried some stuffs but it doesn't work.
Here is my actual code that works if I am in the home page..

```
  $(".anchor-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top + (-117)
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(this).attr('href')`, use any selector in the top of page where you want to scroll. 
If you have `#home` id in top then you need to use:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#home').offset().top + (-117)
}, 1000);
```