# Direct link to YouTube comments

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to link directly to the comments section of a YouTube page?

I know that this can be done [using anchors and div ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash), but this has been unsuccessful when I applied it to a YouTube URL, because YouTube strips the forward slash on page load.

For example, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsGyueVLvQ/#comments` becomes `?v=eRsGyueVLvQ#comments`

Is this possible, or should this be chalked up to a feature request?

Answer (score 19):

You can make a certain comment appear at the top of the comment section by clicking on how long ago it was posted (e.g. `2 years ago`).

This will take you to the same YouTube video, but with a URL which looks something like this: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&lc=COMMENT_ID` (just like in Mr.Rebot's answer).

You can also do this for replies as well.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it's that simple. My whole life I was clicking on peoples comments from the notifications menu and thinking "oh the YouTube algorithm actually finds the best comments and brings it to the top and highlights it". I never realised that it's just because it's the comment link I clicked on from notifications menu.

Comment: This is a very useful, thanks. I'm looking for something though that puts the comments at the top of the page when they click the link (i.e an anchor link), such as: external-site.com/#anchor

Comment: There is no way to link and scroll to actual comment in page with url?

Answer (score 3):

If you will use the [CommentThreads:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list):

> Returns a list of comment threads that match the API request parameters.

Code Snippets:

```
// Sample PHP code for commentThreads.list

function commentThreadsListByVideoId($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->commentThreads->listCommentThreads(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

commentThreadsListByVideoId($service,
    'snippet,replies',
    array('videoId' => 'kmXXXLBL3Nk'));
```

Then you can create a link with with the URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&lc=COMMENT_ID
```

This link is not generated in the API so you should create a function for this.

Comment: Since I want to link directly to the section of the youtube page where the comments begin, I am always going to want to link to the very first comment. Would that just be `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&lc=1` ?

Comment: There is a generated commentID for the specific comment which you can use to your link. You can follow the link provided above to get the commentID.

Comment: Thanks. If more recent comments are added though, will that link go further and further away from the start of the comment section? In case I didn't explain well, I want this to be an external link that takes viewers to the actual youtube page. Specifically, to the top of the comments section.

Comment: I see. So the code you posted above will generate the commentID of the most recent comment? That way, it's always the top of the comments thread?

Comment: I have just tested. I can see using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&lc=COMMENT_ID it will make linked comment on top of other comments, but thats all. Can you actually scroll to comment in the page?