# Anchor link with subpages

Tags: jquery, anchor, anchor-scroll, data-paging

Bonjour From France !

I am working on a webapp and I'm stuck with how to go to a specific div in a page from another :
I have one page (myapp/#!/shop.php) with a list of products and a link on every product to a detail page (myapp/#!/shop-item.php).
The user scroll to a product from the list page, click on an item to see details.
I need to create a link in the detail page to go back to the list page BUT specifically to the last Item the user clicked on (to avoid the user to scroll another time the complete list).

Notes :
* I am using a jquery template
* The list page contains headers and mysql queries
* Notice that the link  between pages contains **myapp/#!/** + thenameofpage.php

Thanks for helps !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don not do nothing at the moment. So I have no code for instance...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your paging works, but can you use a [regular anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash)? e.g. `myapp/#!/shop.php#item5`

Comment: I finally understood that My problem is that I am using Framework7 and I do not know how to do an achor link...