# JavaDocs - adding hyperlink to each section and including a script tag for each html file

Tags: html, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

So I am using this plugin for generating javadocs:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and to generate the docs I use: `mvn javadoc:javadoc`

and I get something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to put an `<a>` or `<div>` in the html sections so that I can hyperlink to it using this technique? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835151/1223975
2. I need to include a javascript  tag in each html file for the generated javadocs. Is there a way to tell the plugin to include this script tag in each html file? In the `<head>`? Or really anywhere since it's for styling.

For example, to solve #2, I tried adding this above each class in my project:

```
/*
 * <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
 **/
public class Foo {}
```

but that didn't seem to work, the script tag doesn't get added to the html.

Comment: Here's a link to the javadoc plugin documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve #2, I just did a hack. I copied the source from the google-code-prettify library to a shared .js file that is already loaded by javadoc pages.

https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js

I copied the above code from the link into a .js file into `target/site/apidocs/script.js`. This isn't a great solution if the javadoc format changes but will work for now. I'd prefer to be able to declaratively load `<script>` tags at will in my javadoc comments if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out #2, so my syntax was wrong, instead of this:

```
/*
 * <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
 **/
public class Foo {}
```

should be:

```
/**
 * <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
 */
public class Foo {}
```

then it will load the script it whatever page of the javadocs you are on.