# How does answer or comment linking works (stackoverflow,wikipedia)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

Stackoverflow allows comment or answer linking . It means it allows  you to create a link to a specific answer or a comment on a post.

My question is how does it drags the browser to that specific post

I know they use id for a specific comment or post.

Which technology or technique is used to create  something like this?

I have gone through few post in meta.stackexchange.com but it does not answer the technique or technology used to create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Anchors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (or `<a />` tags) with fragments and element ids.

```html
<!-- <a> element links to the section below -->
<p><a href="#Section_further_down">
  Jump to the heading below
</a></p>

<!-- Heading to link to -->
<h2 id="Section_further_down">Section further down</h2>
```

Comment: I will accept this answer. Once I test this on my system. Thanks. Can you suggest more specific or generic  question ? So If anyone searches this again they will be redirected here. It could benefit the stackoverflow community.

Comment: @Aman The `#` url syntax is general - you can even enter it manually in your browser. For example this is the link to the History section of the article on HTML on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#History

Comment: *can you suggest a question* - how about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash I found it via https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=link+to+part+of+page