# How can i open HTML file on a specific header in QT?

Tags: html, qt, qurl, qdesktopservices

I use help button *(from QDialog)* to open an HTML file, but i want it to **open on specific header** (<*h1*>, <*h2*>, etc.), depending on from which window i use help button.

This is how i open HTML:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/HELP.html"));
```

How can i do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Answer (score 0):

When you add `id` attributes to your headlines, you can use anchor links:

`<h1 id="somename">my headline</h1>`

Your link can then look like this:

`QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/HELP.html#somename"));`

Comment: When i write `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/HELP.html#save"));`, i got an error _ShellExecute 'd:/ucheba/GPO/build-ReeGO-Desktop_Qt_5_13_2_MinGW_32_bit-Release/release/HELP.html#save' failed (error 2)._ 
When i write `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///" + QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/HELP.html#save"));`, HTML is opening, but it ignores _#save_.
Id is correct, when i use it for linking in browser, _#save_ appears in browser's line