# Linking to specific part of a webpage, that doesn't have an anchor tag

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, tags, anchor

How do I create a link to a part of long webpage on another website that I don't control, that doesn't have an anchor tag?

I am trying to create a Course Outline Finder chrome extension for my university that you can use to:

- Type course code in input box. (Use JS to filter out all other course codes)
- Click the course code that remains after entering course code.
- Course code link then leads you to a specific part of the university webpage that shows a list of course outlines for that specific course.

Ideally the webpage would have given an anchor tag like the following:

```
<h2 id="anchor">COMP150</h2>
```

Which I would then be able to link by doing the following:

```
<a href="https://www.ufv.ca/calendar/CourseOutlines/PDFs/COMP/#anchor>
```

But the website unfortunately doesn't have any id's for the h2 tags.
It instead has this:

```
    <h2>COMP 150</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="COMP150-20000927.pdf">COMP150-20000927.pdf</a>Effective Fall 2012</li>
        <li><a href="COMP150-20011207.pdf">COMP150-20011207.pdf</a>Effective Fall 2019</li>
      </ul>
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I found a solution using text (instead of anchors) by JOUTI:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:~:text=JOUTI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using text (instead of anchors) by JOUTI here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:~:text=JOUTI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:%7E:text=JOUTI)

Test:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20this%20link)

Comment: That actually does not work for me from the link here. It works from elsewhere
The [link Jouti posted does work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link)

Comment: That's odd. Seems to work in comments but not on an answer post. I edited my answer to copy-paste your link. The link via your comment works, but won't via answer post. I wonder why.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the ID yourself in your extension:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2")
  .forEach(header => header.id = header.id ? header.id : header.textContent.trim())
```

Alternatively ask them to add an ID to their headers - they might agree