# Making a clickable header in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Im almost done with my portfolio using React, the code below is my Header.jsx component. Im trying to make it to where if i click contact or about, itll take me to that portion of the page. My code is below;

import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Header = () => {

const [active, setActive] = useState("nav_menu")
const [icon, setIcon] = useState("nav_toggler")

```
const navToggle = () => {
    if(active === "nav_menu") {
        setActive("nav_menu nav_active")
    } else setActive("nav_menu")


    if(icon === "nav_toggler") {
        setIcon("nav_toggler")
    } else setIcon("nav_toggler")

}

return (
    <header>
        <div className='headContainer flexSB'>
            <div className='logo'>
                <img src="./images/services-portfolio.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul className={active}>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div onClick={navToggle} className={icon}>
                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>


        </div>
    </header>
)
```

}

export default Header

Comment: is your portfolio all one page? if so using hash tag would work, ie `<a href="#about">About</a>` then set `id="about"` on the outer most element of the about section

Comment: this code i pasted here is just the header component. but if you mean from the webpage itself, then yes. everything is on one page.

Comment: this is what youre trying to do yeah? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash

Comment: I got it to work! I followed your first comment benmneb

Answer (score 0):

If your portfolio is all one page, then using [hash tag links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash) would work, ie

`<a href="#about">About</a>`

then set

`id="about"`

on the outer most element of the section of the page you want the link to go to.

---

If you have a sticky header on your site, [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/) has some great tips about getting these links to work without the header cropping the top of the element the page is scrolling to.